# context menu on a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, user-controls, contextmenu

I've written a usercontrol that, in essence, is a palette of widgets. When the user right-clicks on one of the widgets that I've drawn on the control, I want to allow the user to delete the selected widget.

In the MouseClick event handler of my usercontrol, I determine which widget the user has clicked on. I then check to see if the mousebutton is the right button. If so, I display a menu that should allow the user to delete the widget:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
    ContextMenu deleteMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem("Delete...", new System.EventHandler(this.onDeleteMenuItem_Click));
    deleteMenu.MenuItems.Add("Delete");
    deleteMenu.Show(this, new Point(mouseXPosition, mouseYPosition));
}
```

My handler for this item is:

```
private void onDeleteMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleting...");
}
```

When I right-click, the menu is displayed, but the handler never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it is because you are not adding the menu item:

Change this line of code:

```
deleteMenu.MenuItems.Add("Delete");
```

to:

```
deleteMenu.MenuItems.Add(deleteItem);
```

Comment: D'oh! Thank you. As obvious as that was, I looked at it for hours and didn't see it.